# a cleaner way to approach try except in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

So, let say I have 3 different calls called `something`, `something1` and `something2`.

and right now, im calling it like

```
try:
   something
   something1
   something2
except Keyerror as e:
   print e
```

Note that in the above code, if something fails, something1 and something2 will not get executed and so on.

The wanted outcome is

```
try:
    something
except KeyError as e:
    print e
try:
    something1
except KeyError as e:
    print e
try:
    something2
except KeyError as e:
    print e
```

How can I achieve the above code without so many try except blocks.

**EDIT:**

So, the answer I chose as correct worked. But some of the others worked as well. I chose that because it was the simplist and I modified it a little.

Here is my solution based on the answer.

```
runs = [something, something1, something2]
for func in runs:
    try:
        func()
    except Keyerror as e:
        print e
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this, assuming you wrap things in functions:

```
for func in (something, something1, something2):
    try:
        func()
    except Keyerror as e:
        print e
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a little context manager I've used for similar situations:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ignoring(*exceptions):
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions or Exception as e:
        print e

with ignoring(KeyError):
    something()

# you can also put it on the same line if it's just one statement
with ignoring(KeyError): something1()

with ignoring(KeyError): something2()
```

A Python 3 version could let you parameterize what to do when an exception occurs (the keyword-only arguments are needed here):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ignoring(*exceptions, action=print):
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions or Exception as e:
        callable(action) and action(e)
```

Then you could pass in some function other than `print` (such as a logger, assumed to be a function named `log`) or if you don't want anything, pass in `None` (since it checks to see if the action is callable):

```
with ignoring(KeyError, action=log): something()
```

Comment: Python 2.7 can also parameterize what to do when an exception occurs.

Comment: The way I've written it you need keyword-only args, which is a Python 3 only feature AFAIK. You could accept a single `exception` argument and then the caller would pass in a tuple if more than one is needed.

Comment: Keyword-only arguments are backported to Python 2.7.

Comment: @nightcracker: Are you sure? I get a `SyntaxError` when I try to `def f(*args, x): pass` in 2.7.3.

Comment: I can confirm no keyword-only args in 2.7. There was a [patch for it](http://bugs.python.org/issue1745) but it was rejected. Just tried it in 2.7.5.

Comment: My bad everyone, there is no inherent support for keyword arguments in Python 2.7 (I accidently left off the * from args while testing). However the behaviour can still be achieved portably across both versions by doing something like this: `from __future__ import print_function; def ignoring(*exceptions, **kwargs): action = kwargs.get("action", print)`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like this:

```
def safe_do(*statements):
    for statement, args, kwargs in statements:
        try:
            statement(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyError as e:
            print e

# usage:
safe_do(
        (something1, [], {}),
        (something2, [], {}),
        )
```

But if you are expecting only one element to be missing in statements than why don't you `if` it?

```
if some_key1 in some_dict1:
    something1

if some_key2 in some_dict2:
    something2
```

much more readable and without any *magic*

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility

```
def mydec(func):
  def dec():
    try:
      func()
    except KeyError as e:
      print(e)
  return dec

@mydec
def f1():
  print('a')

@mydec
def f2():
  print('b')
  raise KeyError('Test')

f1()
f2()
```

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on whether or not you're doing similar tasks, or very different tasks. For example, if your `something` lines are all very similar you could do the following:

```
def something(my_dict):
    try:
        d = my_dict['important_key']  # Just an example, since we
        return d                      # don't know what you're really doing
    except KeyError as e:
        print e

something(dict1)
something(dict2)
something(dict3)
```

However, if your tasks are wildly different, this approach may not be applicable. To a certain degree you're asking "How do I write efficient code", and the answer to that depends on what code you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

In python3, if you want to input a function with its args and kwargs, you can use the code below:

```
def safe_do(**statement):
    try:
        statement['func'](*statement['args'],**statement['kwargs'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(statement['func'])
        print(statement['args'])
        print(statement['kwargs'])
def divide(a,b):
  print(a/b)
safe_do(func=divide,args=[1,0],kwargs={})
```

In [my colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VQ5ql-RGfdcBKrNgmf4Q9kiozbDQwZ_b?usp=sharing), I presented it.